# How to give stored procedured name dynamically in Talend tDBSP

Tags: talend, talend-mdm

I have a table name called abc in oracle db, which has two fields S.No, and procedure name. I am calling the S.No and procedure name, where SNO is input given by me (while executing the job, it asks for S.No). Once I get the procedure name related to that particular S.No, I am sending procedure name to tFixedFlowInput and from there, connecting to the tDBSP (Oracle) to execute the procedure.

In tDBSP (Oracle), I want to give the stored procedure name got from tFixedFlowInput dynamically. So, in future I need to give only the S.No, as input and it should execute the related stored procedure.  Kindly help me in achieving this.

Also, the procedure has one input parameter.

Comment: Did you tried to use tsetglobalvar component

Comment: can you let me know how to do define/use that